# How to flex-basis a div based on the height of the image it contains?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a row on my page with a fixed height of 528px and two divs side by side within that row. It's in React/styled-components below, but I think it will make sense:

```
      <Row justify="space-between">
        <Screenshot size='small' src={`image.png`} />
        <Subsection />
      </Row>

const PortfolioRow = styled(FlexContainer)` // this is a div with display: flex
  width: 100%;
  height: 528px;
`;
```

My Screenshot component:

```
const Screenshot = ({
  src,
  size,
  ...props
}) => {


  return (
    <Container size={size}>
      <Img src={src} />
    </Container>
  )
};

const Container = styled(FlexContainer)`
  padding: ${props => props.size === 'small' ? '40px' : '80px'};
  background-color: #34a5e2;
`;

const Img = styled.img`
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  max-width: 100%;
`;
```

The Screenshot component can receive different sized images as props. I don't want to set a fixed width or even a flex-basis because it either squishes/stretches the image, or it leaves extra space around the sides of the image.

What I'd like to happen is for the image height to always be 528px - 40px of padding on top and bottom. The image should retain its proportions and there should only be 40px of padding on left and right. The Subsection component will take up the remaining horizontal space.

I've tried adding

```
height: calc(528px - 80px); /* Row height minus the padding */
width: auto;
```

to the Img component, but the image still gets squished.

This seems like it should be simple, how have others handled this before?

SOLUTION based on comment from G-Cyrillus:

```
const PortfolioScreenshot = ({
  src,
  size,
  backgroundColor,
  ...props
}) => {


  return (
    <Container size={size} color={backgroundColor}>
      <Img src={src} size={size} />
    </Container>
  )
};

const Container = styled(FlexContainer)`
  padding: ${props => props.size === 'small' ? '40px' : '80px'};
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`;

const Img = styled.img`
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  max-width: ${props => props.size === 'small' ? 'inherit' : '100%'};
  height: ${props => props.size === 'small' ? 'calc(528px - 80px)' : 'auto'}; 
  flex-shrink: ${props => props.size === 'small' ? '0' : 'inherit'};
`;
```

Comment: and setting a static height is not enough ? : base code to test : `img {height:528px;flex-shrink:0;}` or `img {height:448px;flex-shrink:0;}` ?

Comment: This did it! Thanks :)